# Dynamic Generation of Fields for a Custom Content Type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views, cck

I am developing a custom content type by using CCK and new module as described in
http://drupal.org/node/1044248

Besides the standard fields, it can have 1 - N additional fields. 
N is dynamic.

Instead of creating, say 5 pre-defined fields, I would like to support N fields, which the user can add as many he/she wants.

Is this possible to do using CCK in Drupal 6.X? Or, can it be done via any other way?

Thanks

Comment: Just thinking - instead creation of 1 - N additional fields you can change how many values can have field (from 1 to unlimited). If all fields are equal regarding structure. In this case you can just change field settings.

Comment: Good idea - can you elaborate more on how to do in in Durpal CCK UI? Each field becomes a column in a table in DB. Each row corresponds to a node. So, I am not sure how you can do it in Drupal CCK. Yes, all the fields are of text structure.

Answer (score 0):

Did not realise there was a property for selecting number of fields with unlimited option that can be selected - thought it might help who might have overlooked that field.

Comment: You could checkmark your answer. (And you could maybe include more details about where to find this option, for others with the same problem.)